# Magento 1.7 CE - change group of custom attribute in product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I added a custom attribute in the products table:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group'             => 'General',
    'type'              => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Custom Attribute',
    'input'             => 'text',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'searchable'        => true,
    'filterable'        => true,
    'comparable'        => true,
    'visible_on_front'  => true,
    'unique'            => false,
    'apply_to'          => 'simple,configurable,virtual',
    'is_configurable'   => false
));
```

It shows up correctly in the `general` tab of the product edit screen.
I should have created a new custom tab for this attribute.
How can I change it so it shows up in a new custom tab?

Saw this similar question here [move to another group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981168/move-a-product-attribute-to-a-new-group-in-magento-admin)
But the group does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with this solution to move an attribute to another tab/group.

```
$setId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId('catalog_product');

$groupId = $installer->getAttributeGroupId($installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product'), $setId, 'Custom group');

$installer->addAttributeToGroup('catalog_product', $setId, $groupId, 'shop_id', 1000);
$installer->addAttributeToGroup('catalog_product', $setId, $groupId, 'size_chart', 9010);
```

This will move the attribute to another group. Note that I first had to add a new attribute (I needed that anyway) with the correct group name before changing the group id.

Comment: What I noticed that for some products the attributes `shop_id` and `size_chart` were still in the `General` tab ?! And for most other products it was moved to the custom group.

Comment: Found the problem of that: in some attribute sets the `shop_id` and `size chart` was in the wrong group. So is that a different group then?

Answer (score 0):

For the `group` element set the name of your new tab. If the tab does not exist then Magento creates it automatically.

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group'             => 'New tab label here',
    ...
));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I need it for an existing custom attribute. I just see this is a similar question asked here [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981168/move-a-product-attribute-to-a-new-group-in-magento-admin) . But the new group does not exist yet.

Comment: Then try to adapt the answer in that question. Or you can delete the attribute and recreate it (if you don't have values already for it)

Comment: Ok,  will use the code in that answer. (Deleting is not an option due to existing values).